# Angular - unit testing a controller that consumes a promise on initialization. ( Jasmine )

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

You have a controller `ExampleController` which consumes a method on a service `RequestService.data` during it's initialization, and you just want to test that the  controllers (scope).property is set to a value in the response:

#### ExampleController:

```
app.controller('ExampleController'
            , ['$scope','RequestService', function($scope, RequestService){
  var ex = this;  
  (function initialize(){
    RequestService.
      data().
      then(function RSresp(info){
       ex.property = info.data.property;
      }
  })();
}]
```

#### RequestService:

```
app.service('RequestService', ['$http', function($http){
   this.data = function RSdata(){
     var closure = {prop: 'val', derp: 'aderp'};
     var url = 'http://aWebsite.' + closure.prop + '.com/' + closure.derp;
     return $http.get(url);
   }
}]);
```

#### Unit test:

```
describe('on initialization, ExampleController',function(){
 var controller, injector, $httpBackend, $scope, RequestService;

  beforeEach(function(){
   inject(function(_$injector_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_){
     injector = _$injector_;
     $scope = _$rootScope_.new();
     $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
     controller = _$controller_('ExampleController', {$scope : $scope});
     RequestService = injector.get('RequestService');
   })
  })

  beforeEach(function(){
    $httpBackend.
       when('GET', 'http://aWebsite.val.com/aderp').
       respond({property: 'value'});
  });

  afterEach(function(){
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('has a property "property" with a value "value" ', function(){
    expect(controller.property).toBeDefined();
    expect(controller.property).toBe('value');
  });
});
```

---

I've tried a bunch of different things like:

```
expect($scope.property).toBeDefined();
```

or

```
spyOn(RequestService, 'data');
// or spyOn(RequestService, 'data').andCallThrough();
expect(controller.property).toBeDefined();
expect(RequestService.data).toHaveBeenCalled;
```

---

#### Karma's saying:

`"Error: Unflushed requests"`
or
`on initialization, ExampleController has a property "property" with a value "value" 
Fail: undefined is not defined.`

`console.log(controller)` doesn't show that the property is set, and it doesn't seem like RequestService is ever called...

I don't know.
All of my tests for RequestService are passing, and the application itself works... but I can't figure out how to write the spec to reflect that.

I've looked at:
[Unit testing promises in controllers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986782/unit-testing-promises-in-controllers-in-angularjs)

and some others that haven't turned out to be irrelevant... but no luck

Comment: well, your assertion would never be true. 'on initialization, ExampleController has a property "property" with a value "value"'. perhaps you could use $httpBackend.expect() and set an expectation of a call to a web service, instead of assigning to a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tests currently try to do far too much.

The responsibility for testing your `$http` requests should be the tests for your `RequestService`. When testing anything that calls `RequestService`, you mock the `RequestService`.

In general, do not go any further than 1 dependency in unit tests (so, `ExampleController` -> `RequestService` would be your limit). Your integration tests will be responsible for testing the full sequence.

So your unit tests should look something like this:

```
describe('on initialization, ExampleController',function(){
 var $q, $controller, injector, $scope, RequestService;

  beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function(_$q_, _$injector_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_){
      $q = _$q_;
      injector = _$injector_;
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      RequestService = injector.get('RequestService');
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(RequestService, 'data');
  });

  describe('with successful data retrieval', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      // mock a success
      RequestService.data.andReturn($q.when({property: 'value'}));
      controller = $controller('ExampleController', {$scope : $scope});

      $scope.$digest(); // fulfil the promises
    });

    it('has a property "property" with a value "value" ', function(){
      expect(controller.property).toBeDefined();
      expect(controller.property).toBe('value');
    });
  });

  describe('with failed data retrieval', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      // mock a fail
      RequestService.data.andReturn($q.reject(null));
      controller = $controller('ExampleController', {$scope : $scope});

      $scope.$digest(); // fulfill the promises
    });

    it('should do something', function(){
      expect('this').toBe('that');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, man/woman/awesome person! I knew it was doing too much, but just couldn't figure out why RequestService.data was never being called (I had a spy on it earlier) - turns out the solution to that problem was to call $digest, but you touched on an important point that I was forgetting- test one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that problem was to call $digest.